# Cannot send email when deploying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, smtpclient, mailmessage

When working locally it works fine, but when publishing the site, the mail function doesn't work. I suspect that the issue might lie with SmtpClient, but I am not sure. Does anyone know if there is a difference in how the network acts when running over the network vs locally?

My code:

```
 public ActionResult SendMail(EmailModel model)
    {
        string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SMTPHOST");
        int port = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SMTPPORT"));
        string receiver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TOADDRESS");
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PASSWORD");

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(host, port);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(receiver, password);
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage mailMsg = null;

        var status = new HttpStatusCode();

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mailMsg = new MailMessage(model.from, receiver, model.subject, model.body);
                smtp.Send(mailMsg);

                return PartialView("_About");
            }
            else
            {
                status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            SendInfoMail("address", "address", "Exception", ex.ToString());
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(status);
    }
```

I think the code throws an exception, but since this only happens when the site is published, I can't debug it.

Comment: You must be logging the exception in `SendInfoMail` function. If not then it more like finding something in black. But any way you can also check for the smtp settings whether they are correct or not.

Comment: Ask your host, they may block SMTP (or your mail server may refuse external connections). Anyway exception content may help.

Comment: use error logging like elmah and save errors in database. Also I can see you have enabled SSL are you using correct port?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana I am using port 587, but I have also tried port 25. Port 25 doesn't seem to work at all, even locally. You are right, some error logging might be necassary